# Angular 2 - how to use other component as Service and rad its data

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, typescript, angular, components

I currently work deeply on DI in Angular 2. 
I have one component, a HomeComponent which is a parent component to my TilesComponent.

In tiles component I have only:

```
@Component({
    selector:'tiles',
    templateUrl: 'app/tiles/tile.component.html',

})


export class TilesComponent{
    @Input() report: any;
    @Input() selectedCurrencyShort: any;

     constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private location: Location, private _insaService: InsaService) {

        if (!this._authService.isLoggedIn()) {
            this.location.replaceState('/');
            this.router.navigate(['LoginComponent']);
            return;
        }
    }



}
```

and in template:

```
 <div class="ui-g">
                <div class="ui-g-2 ui-md-2">
                   <div class="panel panel-default" style="width:100%; height:40%;text-align:center;">
                       <div class="panel-body">
                         <div class="row"><h5>Total Assets</h5></div>
                         <div class="row">{{selectedCurrencyShort}} {{report.TotalAsset}}</div>
                  </div>
                 </div>
               </div> 
                <div class="ui-g-2 ui-md-2">
                   <div class="panel panel-default" style="width:100%; height:40%;text-align:center;">
                       <div class="panel-body">
                         <div class="row"><h5>Total Liquidity</h5></div>
                         <div class="row">{{selectedCurrencyShort}} {{report.TotalLiquidity}}</div>
                  </div>
                 </div>
               </div>     
                <div class="ui-g-2 ui-md-2">
                   <div class="panel panel-default" style="width:100%; height:40%;text-align:center;">
                       <div class="panel-body">
                         <div class="row"><h5>Unerealised P/L</h5></div>
                         <div class="row">{{selectedCurrencyShort}} {{report.TotalProfit}}</div>
                  </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
                 <div class="ui-g-2 ui-md-2">
                   <div class="panel panel-default" style="width:100%; height:40%;text-align:center;">
                       <div class="panel-body">
                         <div class="row"><h5>Performance TWR</h5></div>
                         <div class="row">{{report.TWPerformance | number:'.1-2'}}%</div>
                  </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
               <div class="ui-g-2 ui-md-2">
                   <div class="panel panel-default" style="width:100%; height:40%;text-align:center;">
                       <div class="panel-body">
                         <div class="row"><h5>Capital In/Out Flow</h5></div>
                         <div class="row">{{selectedCurrencyShort}} {{report.TotalInOutAmount}}</div>
                  </div>
                 </div>
               </div> 
               <div class="ui-g-2 ui-md-2">
                   <div class="panel panel-default" style="width:100%; height:40%;text-align:center;">
                       <div class="panel-body">
                         <div class="row"><h5>Performance</h5></div>
                         <div class="row">{{selectedCurrencyShort}} {{report.Performance}}</div>
                  </div>
                 </div>
               </div>     
            </div>
```

I need to connect it with my HomeComponent, so I define inside home component html:

```
<tiles [report]="report" [selectedCurrencyShort]="selectedCurrencyShort"></tiles>
```

where I bind report data from Home component to property report in my tile component and it works fine.

Now, I need to put

```
<tiles [report]="report" [selectedCurrencyShort]="selectedCurrencyShort"></tiles>
```

inside other component, for example component B. How can I use it and get report data and selectedCurrencyShort data from Home Component?  How it needs to be injected properly (I want to somehow use my HomeComponent as Service)?Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a seperate service to hold the data:

```
@Injectable()
export class ReportService {
    public report: any;
    public selectedCurrencyShort: any;
}
```

In your main component (App or something like that) you add it to the providers:

```
@Component({
    ...
    providers: [ReportService]
})
export class App {...}
```

Then you inject it into all components where you need it:

```
export class TilesComponent {
    constructor(...,
                private _reportService: ReportService) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}

export class HomeComponent {
    constructor(...,
                private _reportService: ReportService) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}

export class ComponentB {
    constructor(...,
                private _reportService: ReportService) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

And in your template you bind to it like this:

```
<div class="row">{{_reportService.selectedCurrencyShort}} {{_reportService.report.TotalAsset}}</div>
```

Then you don't need to pass it down with `@Input` anymore! :)